# Multiple Regex pattern in one single element Angular

Tags: regex, angular, angular2-formbuilder, angular-formbuilder

I want to use multiple regex pattern in one element `textarea`. I am using `Angular` with `ReactiveForms Module` with `Validators` class.

The pattern is : `"user@example.com, user@, @example.com, @.example.com"`. I want these 4 patters to be applied in multiple `textarea` elements. How can i do this?

Here is my current code:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  sender__radioBtn: [''],
  sender__emailaddress: ['', Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$'],
  receiver__radioBtn: [''],
  reciever__emailaddress: ['', Validators.email],
  reciever__dropdown: [''],
  reciever__checkbox: [''],
  reciever__emailaddress2: ['', Validators.email]
});
```

Also if user write wrong pattern, then how can i show custom error on the `HTML page`. I do not want to use Bootstrap class, I want to show some custom message. How can I do this? I am new to angular and regex and am a little bit confused with Forms and validations.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is just use one regex for your regex validation, but in case you want to show differenet error message for those regex, you can use custom validation function, for example:

```
validateRegexs(regex: string, key: string): ValidatorFn {
  const regexExp = new RegExp(regex)
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const isInvalid = regexExp.test(control.value);
    const res = {} as any;
    if(isInvalid) {
      res[key] = {value: control.value}
      return res;
    }
    return null;
  };
}

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  emailaddress: this.fb.control('', [
    this.validateRegexs(someregex, 'regex1'),
    this.validateRegexs(someregex, 'regex2')
  ])
});

get emailaddress(): FormContrl {
  return this.myForm.get('emailaddress') as FormControl;
}
```

and in your html, you can set some dom with error message like this:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="emailaddress">
<span *ngIf="emailaddress.invalid && emailaddress.errors['regex1']">This is error message 1</span>
<span *ngIf="emailaddress.invalid && emailaddress.errors['regex2']">This is error message 2</span>
```

Comment: maybe this is helpful: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-reactive-forms